# Border of bitmap appears different on different device in Android

Tags: android, bitmap

Hello I am trying to make the bitmap to rounded shape programmatically but I see that in new phone it is less rounded then same APK I installed there I see more rounded corners in old phone. See in the screenshot

Sony Z Xperia 4.3

[image]

Samsung Y Dous 2.3

[image]

I could not understand why it so displaying different border radius somewhat more rounded and less rounded in another device. Any idea how I can resolve this to make same for all devices.

Code :

```
public class RoundedCornersDrawable extends BitmapDrawable {

  private final BitmapShader bitmapShader;
  private final Paint p;
  private final RectF rect;
  private final float borderRadius;

  public RoundedCornersDrawable(final Resources resources, final Bitmap bitmap) {
    super(resources, bitmap);
    bitmapShader = new BitmapShader(getBitmap(), Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
    p = getPaint();
    p.setAntiAlias(true);
    p.setShader(bitmapShader);
    final int w = (int) (resources.getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels) - (int) TypedValue.applyDimension( TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 35, resources.getDisplayMetrics());
    final int h = 200;
    rect = new RectF(0, 0, w, h);
    borderRadius = 15;
  }

  @Override
  public void draw(final Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, borderRadius, borderRadius, p);
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that has to do with the different screen densities of the devices (how many pixel are in one inch of the screen). One pixel is not the same size on the screen on all devices. [Here's](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) some info about supporting multiple screens. You should also have a look at [DisplayMetrics](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html), there you can get the current screen density that you should add to you height and radius calculations.

Alternatively, you could use the display width as basis for the height and the radius calculation. Right now you are using a fix amount of 200 and 15 pixel.

Something like this:

```
h = w/10;
borderRadius = h / 3;
```